# Count mutual items

Tags: sql

My sql table is below

```
create table t (id1 varchar(10),id2 varchar(2))
insert into t values
('a','b'),
('a','c'),
('a','d'),
('b','a'),
('b','c')
```

I'm trying to get below output

```
a b 1
```

1 because item 'C' is common to both a and b

I have tried below sql which gives count of items but not common item count

```
select  t1.id1,t2.id2,count(*) from t t1 join t t2 
on  t1.id1=t2.id2
group by t1.id1,t2.id2
```

Comment: Why `a b` and not `b a` or both?

Comment: So, if you `insert ('b', 'b')` then you should get 2, right?

Comment: There can't be (b,b)

Comment: (a,b) = (b,a) both directionals

Comment: What output would you expect with ('c','c')?

Comment: but how does SQL Query know it should only show a,b because b,a also has the same match? What if you had a,b once and b,a twice?

Answer (score 0):

The id2 of the self-join is equal, both 'c'.
And this would get (a, b) and (b, a).
So to get only (a, b) you can take the one where id1 is lower than the other id1.  This also avoids tupples like (x,x).

> ```
> select t1.id1, t2.id1, count(*) 
> from t t1 
> join t t2 
>   on t1.id2 = t2.id2 and t1.id1 < t2.id1
> group by t1.id1, t2.id1
> ```
>
> ```
> id1 | id1 | count
> :-- | :-- | ----:
> a   | b   |     1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e90996694da71feaea105b69eaa745d3)*